# Using returned outputs from one function in another in Python

Tags: python, function, sum, return, store

new to Python - struggling with functions. - Image of code attached.

It inputs the name & scores just fine with the validation checks.
I need to use the scores input by the user and total them. 
However, when I've tried to sum(score) it doesn't like it.
I can't work out how to sum the 4 total scores.

Please help :) Also would love any feedback on the style of coding etc.
Thanks in advance x

[Image: Code in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R38My.png)

Comment: Can you paste the actual code instead?

Comment: At the expense of sounding sulky my answer shows how to use the returned outputs from one function in another, as you asked in the question. Do post your actual code another time to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the main function to be something like:

```
def GetStudentInput():
  score = 0
  for i in range (4):
      print("Mrs Pearson's Class Test Score Data")
      name = CheckStringInput("What's Your Name: ")
      score += CheckNumericInput("What's Your Score: ")
  print(score)
```

This eliminates the need for an extra function and avoids using a list since you don't appear to need the individual values elsewhere -- only the sum total.

Comment: Thanks so much that's done it perfectly :) I've added a bit extra in but is working now - thanks for the help!  --  print("Total score: " + str(score)) --

Answer (score 0):

In the absense of code for people to see, we have something like

```
def get_stuff():
    for i in rnage(4):
        name = input("Name?")
        score = int(input("Score?"))
```

and another function

```
def TotalScore():
    pass
```

How do we call total score?
Answer: Make sure we don't forget the user inputs and return them:

```
def get_stuff():
    names = []
    scores = []
    for i in range(4):
        names.append(input("Name?"))
        scores.append(int(input("Score?")))
    return names, scores
```

and take the scores in the summing function:

```
def TotalScore(scores):
    return sum(scores)
```

This, of course, changes the calling code.
For example, you need to capture the returns when you call `get_stuff`:

```
names, scores = get_stuff()
total = TotalScores(scores)
```